# Differences between external domains and subdomains when using EasyXDM?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Are there any differences between external domains, and subdomains when using [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net)?

I am wondering about:

- Security Issues
- Cross Browser Support
- Speed
- Anything minor or major

I really can't find much information about this, so I figure that it must be the same?

To explain further which one is the best setup of these:

1. example.com <-> sub.example.com
2. example.com <-> sub.other.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one thing that make this thing easier, I found `document.domain`:

> There is one exception to the same origin rule. A script can set the
>   value of document.domain to a suffix of the current domain. If it does
>   so, the shorter domain is used for subsequent origin checks.
>
> For example, assume a script in the document at
>   http://store.company.com/dir/other.html executes the following
>   statement: document.domain = "company.com";
>
> After that statement executes, the
>   page would pass the origin check with
>   http://company.com/dir/page.html. However, by the same reasoning,
>   company.com could not set document.domain to othercompany.com.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript